# Spring web flow externalRedirect with expression

Tags: spring, spring-webflow-2

I am trying to redirect to a server relative url using externalRedirect in view-state as below :

```
<view-state id="perspectives" view="externalRedirect:serverRelative:${flowScope.url}">
</view-state>
```

Or

```
<view-state id="perspectives" view="externalRedirect:serverRelative:#{flowScope.url}">
</view-state>
```

And it looks like it is not evaluating the expression in the view attribute and redirecting to this url `"http://localhost:8080/selector/app/'serverRelative:'%20+%20flowScope.url"`.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help in advance!

-Krishna

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
<view-state id="a"
    view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:#{flowScope.externalRedirectUrl}">
```

and i am using spring webflow 2.4.0.RELEASE